# Wait until a requested event is finished in X11

Tags: x11, window-resize, xorg, xserver

I want to resize some window with

```
XResizeWindow(display, xid, width, height)
```

which was created by another application and waits until it is really resized.

I tried the following:

```
XSync(display, 0)
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSync just ensures the request has been delivered to the Xserver, and doesn't wait for the other application and/or window manager to deal with the request.

Have you tried registering for [ConfigureNotify](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/configure.html) events on that window?